# Value not displaying in a cell vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple piece of code as below.For both the lines values display in vba console, which means the logic is working. But when I try to show them on excel, the value doesn't display for `wsA.Range("C7").Value` . I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Can anyone help?

```
wsA.Range("C4").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B4").Value
'added logic to tranfer date of assessment
Debug.Print wsA.Range("C4").Value

  wsA.Range("C7").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B8").Value
Debug.Print wsA.Range("C7").Value
Debug.Print wsA.Range("C7").Value = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B8").Value
Debug.Print TypeName(wsA.Range("C7").Value)
```

Output -->

```
7/26/2022
True
Date
```

Comment: Is B7 cell part of some calculations involving these other cells? Try `Debug.Print wsA.Range("C7").Value= ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output Sheet").Range("B8").Value` and `? Typename(wsA.Range("C7").Value)`

Comment: For some reason it says False. No idea what that means in the above context.

Comment: Check the `TypeName` of each one, and if it's numbers, try, say, adding 1 to each. The villain has to appear... Also check the NumberFormat properties

Comment: Updated the format for the cell to Date. Now source and destination formatting match. But no luck.

Comment: After running the code, no. But what if they are dates and, for some reason, different Formats can turn it in trouble. Really strange.

Comment: Rookie mistake. I had a line below which was overwriting the cell. Thanks for the input though. Helped me debug.